# LPD3DXFONT does not draw

Tags: c++, fonts, rendering, direct3d, direct3d9

I am having an issue with my `LPD3DXFONT` not drawing anymore.

`DrawText()` returns D3D_OK and was working just fine earlier.

My primitives and sprites are drawing just fine, but all of the text is no longer visible.

I believe it may have been a change from a render state, but I don't which one could cause the font to stop rendering while leaving sprites just fine.

Comment: BTW, ``D3DX`` is deprecated as is the whole legacy DirectX SDK (see [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx)) Unless you have a specific reason to need to use the 12+ year old Direct3D 9, consider using DIrect3D 11 instead. See [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/).

Answer (score 1):

You should specify these flags before rendering ID3DXFonts: D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND | D3DXSPRITE_SORT_TEXTURE. This code works fine here:

```
// Prepare the device for drawing sprites
if(SUCCEEDED(m_pD3DXSprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND | D3DXSPRITE_SORT_TEXTURE)))
{
    // Render the data on the screen
    m_pD3DXFont->DrawText(m_pD3DXSprite, m_szFPSData, -1, &oTextClientRect[0], 0, 0xFFFF0000); // FPS data

    // End sprite drawing operations
    m_pD3DXSprite->End();
}
```